# Windows Azure TDS emulation on a production non-Azure IIS server

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-worker-roles, nosql

I am developing a c# web application that will be hosted in Windows Azure and use Table Data Storage (TDS).

I want to architect my application such that I can also (as an option) deploy the application to a traditional IIS server with some other NoSql back-end.  Basically, I want to give my customers the option to either pay me in the software as a service model, OR purchase a license of my application that they can install on a (non-azure) production server of their own.

How can I best architect my data layer and middle tier to achieve both goals?

I will likely need a Windows Azure Worker Role and an Azure Queue.  How complicated is to replicate these?  Can I substitue a custom Windows Service and some other queuing technology?

How I can the entities in my data model be written such that I can deploy to Azure TDS or some other storage when not deploying to Azure?  Would MongoDB or similar be useful for this?

Surely there is a way to architect for Azure without being married to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a viable solution.  I found that I can use EF Code First with SQL Server or SQL CE if I design my entities with the same PartitionKey & RowKey compound key structure that Azure Table Storage requires.

With a little help from Lokad Cloud (http://code.google.com/p/lokad-cloud/) to perform the interaction with Azure Table Storage, I was able to craft a common DataContext that provides crud operations against either EF's DbContext OR Lokad's TableStorageProvider.

I even found a nice way to manage relationships between entities and lazy-load them properly.

The solution is a bit complex and needs more testing.  I will blog about it and post the link here when ready.

Comment: Forget it.  After a month of trial and error, it comes down to the fact that Table Storage is just not designed for relational data.  I'm switching to SQL Azure.

Answer (score 2):

> I will likely need a Windows Azure Worker Role and an Azure Queue. How complicated is to replicate these? Can I substitue a custom Windows Service and some other queuing technology?

Yes - a Windows service with some other queuing technology would fit this reasonably well - and worker roles have a main/Run loop which is easy to use within a Windows Service.

> How I can the entities in my data model be written such that I can deploy to Azure TDS or some other storage when not deploying to Azure? Would MongoDB or similar be useful for this?

NoSql is a general term encapsulating lots of different technologies. I think Azure TDS currently belongs to the Key-Value store family of NoSql, while MongoDB is more of a document database offering much richer functionality than TDS - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL_(concept). For mimmicking Azure TDS I think maybe a variant of something like Redis might work (although I believe Redis itself has wider functionality then TDS currently)

In general, it depends on the shape of your data, but I suspect if you can fit it in Azure TDS, then you'll be able to fit it into your choice of other storage too.

> Surely there is a way to architect for Azure without being married to it.

Yes - as you've suggested in your question, you can architect your app so it can work on other technologies instead. In fact, this is quite a similar challenge to the traditional SQL data abstraction methods.  However, I think there are a few places where you'll find TDS pushing you in certain 
directions which won't fit well with other stores - e.g. Azure pushes you much more towards data replication; has very specific rules on keys; offers high performance using very specific mechanisms; and offers limited transaction integrity in very specific situations. These factors may mean that you do have to indeed change some middle tier layers as well as some data layers in order to get the most out of your app in both its Azure and non-Azure variations.

One other thought - It might be easier to offer your clients a multitenant SaaS version on Azure, and a singletenant version hosted on Azure - but this does depend on the clients!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info.  In regards to your last point,  the customers I'm targeting for the non-azure version are primarily intranet scenarios where there is limited or NO Internet access to the end user.  So, nice idea - but no go.  I'll look into Redis.  Thanks.